# MAGENTO - Preço do produto no widget

Tags: magento, widget

Estou com problemas no widget.
Ele exibe os produtos normalmente, mas não sei uma maneira para exibir os preços dos produtos no proprio widget.
**Site para visualização:** [Aniix Store](http://www.aniixstore.com.br/index.php/)

[image: Produtos exibidos no widget]

Comment: Tentou editar no arquivo? Pra exibir o preço?

Comment: Sabe informar qual seria o arquivo para editar?

Comment: Alguem saberia?